# Is it possible to share an entire Google Drive For another user?

Tags: google-drive-api, file-sharing

I want to share an entire Google Drive to another person. Is it possible? I know that it is possible to share a file or folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Drive API, by iterating through every folder and sharing it. Use the [`drive.permissions.insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) method of the API.

Comment: It is just a workaround. it doesn't mean sharing the drive. The issue with this solution is that if we add new file/folder to the drive, won't be available to the other person.